# android linearlayout vertical not showing all

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm doing an android app and I want to do this:

[image: info.xml]

but for now it only shows the photo and textView.

this is my info.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/linear1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/image_profile"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nom_profile"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

   </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/SocialNetworks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Redes Sociales"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaRedesSociales"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="4">
    </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know why is only shows me this, I don't know why is first linearlayout putting horitzontal when I puted vertical! is info.xml not refreshing? or is bad programing?

can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: cause layout_height of linear2 is match_parent, it consumes all vertical space. try to change value of layout_height to wrap_content

Comment: I also would suggest making the parent layout a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use *fill_parent instend of match_parent*, and maybe you should change the height of linear2 :**layout_height='wrap_content'** or **layout_height="0dp" layout_weight="1"**

.

Comment: "FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)"
from [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Please maintain the correct formating when make a comment. In above you didnt make the bold correctly

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is you have given **match_parent** to **android:layout_height** in second LinearLayout and also there is no layout_weight specify for the same. Due to this horizontal linearlayout is taking height as whole screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linear2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/image_profile"
 android:layout_height="48dp"
 android:layout_width="48dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/nom_profile"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/SocialNetworks"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:text="Redes Sociales"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>


<ListView
android:id="@+id/listaRedesSociales"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="4">
</ListView>
```

Try the code above. If this is not working fine please change (or remove) layout_weight attribute from all views (remember to change layout_height attribute also if you remove layout_weight)